# Using getchar() to count spaces, tabs, and newlines

Tags: c

I am currently writing a program that takes a sentence entered by the user and counts the number of Spaces, tabs, and newlines in the sentence, and then prints the values.

The input is terminated by a `!` or `.` or `?` character.

The problem I have is my program doesn't seem to end when any of the above characters is entered at the end of the input.

Here is the current program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int space = 0, tab = 0, newline = 0;
    int sentence;

    printf("Enter a sentence (end by '.' or '?' or '!'):");

    do{
        sentence = getchar();

        if(sentence == ' '){
            ++space;
        }
        else if(sentence == '\t'){
            ++tab;
        }
        else if(sentence == '\n'){
            ++newline;
        }
    }
    while((sentence != '.')||(sentence != '!')||(sentence != '?'));

    printf("Number of space characters: %d\n", space);
    printf("Number of new line characters: %d\n", newline);
    printf("Number of tabs: %d\n", tab);

    return 0;
}
```

I am stumped and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please indent your code. Just like the examples ins your C text book

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ___properly___ indent your code. Machine (Compiler) can read and compile anything, but for humans, it needs to make a little _sense_ while reading a block of text as _code_. When asking question, there was a big orange __How to Format__ box to the right of the text area. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a __[?]__ button giving formatting help. And a preview area  showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace || (or) with && (and) because in your case two of the three conditions will always be true for each and every character that is why while loop goes to infinite.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly! Thank you for the clear explanation as well.